# SSL Cert for multiple subdomains in poste.io

Tags: lets-encrypt

To the poste.io users:
The mail server supports multiple subdomain. So far so good.  But the ssl cert is always of the main domain. i.e., when opening the webmail using the subdomain's url, I see a security exception.

Isn't is possible to extend the lets encrypt's ssl cert list to also have the subdomains so that we have valid certs per subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the option to manually issue ssl cert with multiple subdomains.  After logging into admin console, this option can be found under `System Settings` -> `TLS Certificate` -> `Change Certificate Settings` option.

Comment: also your `/opt/www/.well-known` must be shared with your web server to auto issue certificates by letsencrypt